# ¿Cómo guardar un archivo(pdf) en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo un dilema, he estado queriendo guardar archivos en SQL Server 2014, usando vb.net.

El código de el botón guardar es el siguiente:

```
 Sub SavePDFtoDB()
    Try
        openfd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\"
        openfd.Title = "Open a PDF file"
        openfd.Filter = "PDF files|*.pdf"
        openfd.RestoreDirectory = True
        openfd.ShowDialog()
        TextEdit1.Text = openfd.FileName

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim file = New Byte() {}
        Dim data As Stream = openfd.OpenFile()

        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            data.CopyTo(ms)
            file = ms.ToArray()
        End Using

        'Insert the details into the database
        Abrirconexion()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insertar_Doc", Connection)
        cmd.CommandType = 4
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cliente", LabelControl1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Doc_Name", TextEdit1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", file)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Cerrarconexion()
        MsgBox("Documento Guardado con éxito")
        mostrardocs()
    Catch err As Exception
        MsgBox(err.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

El dilema es que cuando guarda los datos en la base de datos, el campo de `@Content`, me aparecen todos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un campo `varbinary(MAX)`, Cuando todos los tutos y fuentes que he visto y leido, aparece un resultado mas largo:

[image: Imagen sacada de un tuto]

Si alguien me puede orientar donde está el error, no sé si esté a la hora de convertir el archivo a stream y despues a un ARRAY de bytes, o si es alguna configuración extra que tengo que hacerle a SQL, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: No sé cual sea la causa del problema, pero solo estás guardando un signo de porcentaje. Tal vez eso te ayude a identificar el error.